# Telepathic Communication, do Buddhists Believe in it?

Tags: personal-practice, psychic-powers, meditation-visualisation

I know that Buddhists practice compassionate mediation by wishing to free first their loved ones from suffering, than their friends and than the people they have trouble with. Is this only for the individual practicing or can the practice actually reach the object too? (ie. friend)

ps: There is recent scientific evidence for ESP or telepathic communication but did the Buddhists monks know this whole time? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a well known super power attained by advanced meditators. You can find references to such powers in the stories of the Buddha, and in biographies of well known monks.

[Kevatta Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.11.0.than.html):

> "Kevatta, there are these three miracles that I have declared, having
>   directly known and realized them for myself. Which three? The miracle
>   of psychic power, the miracle of telepathy, and the miracle of
>   instruction.

In the Theravada tradition the Visuddhimagga is well known for speaking directly about mastering the occult powers, and in the Madhiyamika tradition (Tibet) the path of the Bodhisattva requires learning to see into the minds of others so they can be helped.

Accounts from recent times, such as the [biography of Ven. Acharya Mun Bhuridatta Thera](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/acariya-mun-bio.pdf) include incidents where he communicated with other monks living elsewhere.

Ajahn Chah's telepathic powers: https://youtu.be/mPIJhO8ipgs

The Buddha forbade speaking about or giving importance to powers with good reason, so in general accounts are not first person, but third person where a monk (usually) talks about witnessing another's powers.

Comment: I've seen other powers mentioned, but I've never seen telepathy.

Comment: Telepathy is one of the more common powers actually -the Buddha explicitly talks about it in Kevatta sutta -  http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.11.0.than.html

Comment: Is the telepathy where a meditator can read (know what's in) the mind of another, or is it where the meditator can write (make something known to) the mind of another? The OP (which says "practice actually reach the object") might assume it means the latter not the former, i.e. projecting and not only receiving. Will metta meditation help not just the meditator but the person who is the object of their meditation?

Comment: Once, while the venerable Anuruddha was meditating in solitude, he considered how, by means of the four Foundations of Mindfulness (satipatthana) the Noble Path that leads to the extinction of suffering can be perfected. Then Moggallana, penetrating Anuruddha's mind by his own, appeared before him through supernormal power and requested him to describe in detail this method of practice (Samy. 52, 1-2). http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/index.php/1._Penetration_of_others'_minds_and_thought-reading_(telepathy)

Comment: @ChrisW It's been my experience that metta helps the person who's the object of the meditation.

Comment: Oh ok thank you for the new information @Buddho :)

Comment: Oh thanks @Buddho :D
that was a really helpful reply :)
I'm going to check out Ajahn Chah's telepathic powers video now
Regards

Comment: @Buddho so the powers of a Tathagata can also be attained by us, not just a Tathagata? I thought we were only able to attain the Five Abhiñña.

Comment: @user5380 the sutta says the powers were to be demonstrated by one of his disciples, not the Buddha himself. Besides powers arise in samatha jhanas, which were already perfected by many in India at the time of the Buddha, they aren't a Buddhist invention. Of course there are powers exclusive to the Buddhas and Bodhisattvas, but telepathy isn't one of them. I'm not really sure about the full list of powers of the Buddhas, but I believe seeing the state of attainment of anyone is one of them.

Comment: Do you have to attain the fourth jhana in the Earth Kasina to be able to solidify things like water? Which give the ability to walk on it? @Buddho

Comment: I don't know unfortunately, I've not investigated powers too much, I find them a distraction to practice.